# Why doesn't this code work to check if a region is occupied?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

I have the code below in my theme to detect if there is a block in the `leftsidebar` region. The problem is that this HTML code still gets output on pages that do not have a block in the `leftsidebar` region. I am at a complete loss as to what the problem is. I do this same code with my other blocks and it works.

Here's the code in my page.tpl.php file...

```
<?php if (!$page['sidebar']): ?>
<div id="content-area" class="one-col">
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if ($page['sidebar'] && !$page['leftsidebar']): ?>
<div id="content-area" class="two-col">
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if ($page['leftsidebar']): ?>
<div id="content-area" class="three-col">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's the block region in my .info file...

```
regions[leftsidebar] = Left Sidebar
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check `<?php if($leftsidebar): ?>`. then add all your markup.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. I believe that's the way to check in Drupal 6. I'm using 7.

Comment: try something like this:

`<?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
<?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
`

Comment: Hmm.. that worked. Wonder why though? I've always printed my block regions like this...

`<?php print render($page['headerimage']); ?>`